# How to set Date Time Column

Tags: 2013, column, date-time

I have a column in my List that is of type Date Time.

By default I want it to  display the Date as Created + 14 days.

I tried the below in the column settings:

[image]

HOWEVER, when I click OK I get the error below:

[image]

Is it not possible to accomplish the desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me: `=[Today]+14`

[image]

And this is end result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use `[Today]+14` for this.